# tcp streams problem c#

Tags: c#, tcp

When i try to connnect to a local IP everything goes wonderfully
but as soon as i use a normal ip, like to connect to a friend of mine outside the lan it just doesn't work

Comment: "It just doesn't work" isn't very informative. What happens?

Comment: Almost certainly firewall related, but your lack of clarity makes me reluctant to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess would be that you may be running into a firewall issue - is there a firewall operating between you and your friend? If so, do you have exceptions for it?

I suggest you use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to analyse what's happening at the network level.

Comment: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it IP:PORT" is the error

Comment: @oidfrosty: That sounds like it's either a firewall issue, or you're not running the relevant app on the target machine.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a combination of firewall and port forwarding. In addition to opening up ports on your firewall, you'll need to forward these ports on your friend's router. [PortForward.com](http://portforward.com/) is a decent resource if you're unfamiliar with port forwarding.

Comment: One other thing to check: make sure you're connecting to your friend's *public* IP address and not his *private* one. Visit [whatismyip.org](http://whatismyip.org/) from your friend's computer to verify his public IP. Also note that many ISPs change the public IP on a regular basis (mine does every day).